# Problems with Powerbuilder and Advantage ODBC

Tags: odbc, powerbuilder

I used to use PowerBuilder with Advantage ODBC. This was some years ago PB 6.51 and the then current versions of Advantage. It all worked smoothly.
Now I've been trying the same thing again. Installed the Advantage oDBC drivers, created the data source and set it up in Powerbuilder. I'm only seeing 1 table with 1 record with 1 field.
I've checked the ODBC setup itself by trying it with Excel and Borland C++ Builder. I can see the data correctly.

So I started working through all the currently available versions of the Advantage ODBC driver. Exactly the same although with one of them Excel crashed.

Finally I found a a really old version of the Advantage driver, Version 3, buried somewhere aobscur on an old hard drive. So I tried installing that. When I tried I saw the tables before it crashed with a DLL conflict. So I de installed all the Advantage drivers via the Windows Add/Remove programmes and reinstall V3. Still a conflict. Removed it via Windows again and Manualy searhed for and removed every DLL that appeared to be from Advantage. Then reinstalled V3. There was still a conflict.

Finally i decided that the only way to test this properly was on a clean install of Windows. I installed a fresh copy of XP in Virtualbox. I'm using XP for this operation as I want to run a couple of 16 bit programmes. In installed Powerbuilder and the V3 Advantage ODBC driver. It all works, no problem.

So I'm certain that the Advantage ODBC driver did work with Powerbuilder but the current versions of the driver don't. The current versions seem fine with everything else.

Does anyone have any idea what the problem is?

Comment: So you are trying to use PB 6.5 (nearly 25 years old) on a current Windows version?

Comment: I thought that XP was of a similar vintage. In fact I had a similar combination working about 12 years ago. Someone from Advantage talked me through it, it involved setting some of the parameters in the Powerbuilder Dbprofile setup.

Answer (score 0):

Check your registry and versions of DLL :

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ODBC\ODBC.INI

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ODBC\ODBC.INI\ODBC Data Sources

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ODBC\ODBC.INI

Comment: You were on the right track. UsageCount was missing from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\Advantage StreamlineSQL ODBC I added it and it all seems OK. It does seem funny that this problem seems to be in versions of the Advantage driver for maybe 15 years now. More so now since advantage and powerbuilder hav ethe same ultimate owners.

Comment: Great ! So valid the answer.